# What is difference between SQL 'select' and PL/SQL 'select' statements?

Tags: sql, select, plsql, cursor

For instance, if I write:

```
            select employee_id,last_name from employees;
```

I will get all the rows existing in "EMPLOYEES" table. 
If I write:

```
            declare
                id employee_id.employees%type;
                ln last_name.employees%type;
            begin
                select employee_id,last_name into id,ln
                from employees
                where employee_id = 100;
                dbms_output.put_line(id||' '||ln);
            end;
```

I get -

```
            100 King
```

If I want to retrieve multiple rows, then I will use CURSOR. But these multiple rows can be retrieved using simple SQL statement I mentioned previously. Then, what's the use of using PL/SQL Declare..Begin..End statement ?

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL is used to write procedures, functions, and programs which require procedural logic which cannot be expressed conveniently as a collection of SQL statements.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL is preferred.

**Advantages:**

*Pre compiled code*- The code is not compiled each time it is executed. This makes the data retrieval faster.

*Code reusability* - No need to write code each time.

*Encapsulation* - Actual business logic is hidden.

*Error handling* - Allows to use predefined and custom exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about whether SQL or PL/SQL,
If you can do it in a single SQL statement - do it and if it doesn't work the way you expected try PL/SQL and if not some other platform if you have it within your application.

Having said that,

SQL (Structured Query Language) is the interface to your database. If you want to change its state or get data out of it you use SQL. It is a declarative language.

PL/SQL is the procedural extension to SQL for Oracle Database. It includes programming constructs such as loops and conditions (if-then). You use it to manage the workflow of SQL transactions.

Basically you use PL/SQL to stitch together SQL statements. It manages the order you process SQL, what to do if you get an error, etc. ("business logic").

Courtesy:- [ASK TOM](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:1000::::::)